# Add prototype functions to JSON from in a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking at this javascript library:
https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune
which is designed for client side browsers, and I am looking to port it over to node.js

I want to be able to have it that anywhere in my code, I can call JSON.prune and it will output a pruned version of a stringified object.

It looks like this uses the concept of prototype to add this function onto JSON. What is the best practices for doing this in a node.js module?

I am thinking I would make some module that would say:

```
file prune.js
====
JSON.prototype.prune = function(){/*bla bla bla*/};
```

But wouldn't that only be visible inside the module itself?

Would I need to say something like this?

```
file json2.js
=====
exports = JSON;
exports.prune = function(){/*bla bla bla*/
```

and then in the method I want to access this in, just say

```
var JSON = require('json2.js');
```

to get the extended functionality? Would that even work?

Is there a better (more standard) way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is application code and not a library or module you're writing, you could do it any way you like.  In terms of "best practices", though, modifying the prototype of an existing constructor is generally avoided.  The easiest approach would be to adapt it into a standalone function like `pruneJSON`, and not modify the `JSON` object at all.

Edit:

For this particular library, you can modify the code at the end (starting at line 114) like this:

```

```
pruneJSON = function (value, depthDecr, arrayMaxLength) {
            if (typeof depthDecr == "object") {
                    var options = depthDecr;
                    depthDecr = options.depthDecr;
                    arrayMaxLength = options.arrayMaxLength;
                    iterator = options.iterator || forEachEnumerableOwnProperty;
                    if (options.allProperties) iterator = forEachProperty;
                    else if (options.inheritedProperties) iterator = forEachEnumerableProperty
            } else {
                    iterator = forEachEnumerableOwnProperty;
            }
            seen = [];
    depthDecr = depthDecr || DEFAULT_MAX_DEPTH;
    arrayMaxLength = arrayMaxLength || DEFAULT_ARRAY_MAX_LENGTH;
            return str('', {'': value}, depthDecr, arrayMaxLength);
};

pruneJSON.log = function() {
            console.log.apply(console,  Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function(v){return JSON.parse(pruneJSON(v))}));
    }
pruneJSON.forEachProperty = forEachProperty; 

module.exports = pruneJSON;
```

```